# How do you send an https request with a local asset image in next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, https, next.js

I am trying to send a local asset image called avatar.png stored in my public/images folder in my next.js folder to a remote http endpoint but I am having trouble appending the image to the formdata of the request. Here is what I tried so far:

```
 formData.append(
      "user_image",
      JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify({
          type: "hi",
          uri: "/images/avatar.png",
          name: "jpeg",
        })
      )
    );
```

Although the uri is correct, the formdata does not contain the avatar.png asset as stored locally when I send the formdata to the remote server using fetch().
Can someone help me append a local asset image in next.js to a https request? Just for clarification, I am trying to get next.js upload a file stored in the public directory of next.js

Comment: you need to open the image, read it, then send the data you've read

Comment: How do I send an asset image stored in the next folder? I don't want the user to upload a photo, but rather let the frontend upload a file stoted in the next public folder

Comment: just like I said